# Is there a Vimscript equivalent to Ruby's `any?'

Tags: vim, lambda

I'd like to refactor this condition in my vimrc:

```
if &term =~ "xterm" || &term =~ "screen" || &term =~ "builtin_gui"
  " do some stuff...
endif
```

In Ruby I'd probably do something like:

```
names = ["xterm", "screen", "builtin_gui"]

if names.any? { |n| &term =~ n }
  " do some stuff...
endif
```

I know Vimscript doesn't have anything like Ruby blocks, but is there any builtin function that would let me do something along these lines?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`=~` a regexp match. So you can use full power of regexp. Either of these should work:

```
&term =~ 'xterm\|screen\|builtin_gui'
&term =~ join(names, '\|')`
```

Comment: Facepalm. Can't believe I overlooked that.

Answer (score 1):

Not really

```
let names = ["xterm", "screen", "builtin_gui"]

if len(filter(names, '&term =~ v:val')) > 0
endif
```

Comment: Oh cool, I forgot it has a filter. Not exactly what I was looking for, but good to know.

Comment: There is `index()`, which appears to be more useful here.